# So slow opening an Android app

Tags: android

I get this in logcat when opening the app after install.
The lagging only happens during the first opening of the app.

I'm building a simple native app using Android Studio and Gradle to build.
See below for the build files:

[image: LogCat message]

[image]

Comment: How do you expect anyone to answer this? With the information you've provided so far, we can't possibly know what your app is doing in between those two logs.

Comment: it takes time for the I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath  to finish. Someone got any idea on what is happening here?

Comment: @Michael Sorry. I attached a new screen shot. The lines inside the red square. The time gap is too big. That time my app have not started yet

Comment: The question is unclear, you don't even specify if you're using Android studio to develop a native app or some kind of cross-platform frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem my using the specific play-services dependency in the Biller gradle file.

Because Im only using the Google Analytics API, so I just need to use     'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0' instead of
'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'.